# Tensorflow: sum over non-NaNs of 2-dimensional tensor in axis 1?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, tensor

Let `tensor` be a tensor where `len(tensor.get_shape()) == 2`.
How to do `np.nansum(tensor, axis=1)`? From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html#numpy.nansum), `nansum` "returns the sum of array elements over a given axis treating Not a Numbers (NaNs) as zero".

I can see how to do this using:

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(tf.is_nan(tensor), tf.zeros_like(tensor), tensor), axis=1)
```

But this seems overly complicated. Is there a better method?

Comment: That seems like a fine method to me (i.e. I don't think there's a fused kernel for this operation).

Comment: If you put this as answer I'll accept it and we can stop showing this question to other users :)

Comment: You're probably right, it's an infrequent edge-case, and `tf.where` introduces negligible slowdown probably. I don't know why I care, I haven't measured.

Comment: You can answer your own question! Probably more appropriate in this case than me answering with "it's fine" :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a better method. Just use the code included in the question.

In fact you can replace NaNs in `tensor` by anything using `tf.where`:

```
tf.where(tf.is_nan(tensor), replacement_tensor, tensor)
```

and of course, setting `replacement_tensor = tf.zeros_like(tensor)` replaces NaNs with zeros.